# Export a JS package from Truffle?

Tags: truffle

Truffle has this whole build process for deploying fronted code that is kinda mediocre. Does anyone know if I can just have Truffle output a single javascript file that will work in a web3 enabled browser and then import that in a much cleaner frontend framework like React?

I guess what is the best way to get all the benefits of Truffle with the secret sauce of React going?

Comment: You can use your own build scripts, for example you can integrate with a webpack project http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/bundling-with-webpack.

Answer (score 1):

What your app needs from truffle is the `truffle-contracts` module, plus json contract definitions that truffle builds when you run `truffle migrate`.

`truffle-contracts` is a normal NPM library, so you can manage it like any other dependency and load it with something like

```
const contract = require('truffle-contracts');
```

The JSON files will change every time you redeploy your contracts, so it's easiest if you can refer directly to them in the place where your `truffle` install keeps them. A simple way to do it is just to keep the `truffle` directory inside the main app directory, then load them with something like

```
const mycontract_json = require('../truffle/build/contracts/MyContract.json');
```

Now you can create contract objects that you can use just like you would in the default truffle build process:

```
var MyContract = contract(mycontract_json);
MyContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    // Interact with your contract as in the Truffle examples
});
```

Your `truffle.js` file can be stripped of everything except the network definitions, as suggested in [the webpack example linked by @Ismael](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/bundling-with-webpack). The build section is no longer needed, as all that Truffle is going to be building is the contract definition files.

See [this project](https://bitbucket.org/edmundedgar/realitycheck/src/6f82516d043b?at=master) for a working example. The code above is based on the code used [here](https://bitbucket.org/edmundedgar/realitycheck/src/6f82516d043b3c489f58b70c03a11c61016b2f77/assets/js/scripts/main.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

If you're a perfectionist about seamless build processes you might want to create a task in your main project's `package.json` or whatever it uses that will jump into the truffle directory and run `truffle migrate --reset` for you, but we didn't bother, and we've never found ourselves wishing we had.